# My jquery and ajax call is not responding and showing unexpected error in console

Tags: ajax

I don't know why my code is giving error while making the ajax call and not responding or working at all. I ran this on an html file. I took this function - getParameterByName() from another stackoverflow answer.tweet-container tag is down the code below outside this script and an empty division.I tried some jquery also.

```js
<script>

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}



$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("working");
  var query = getParameterByName("q")
  // console.log("query");
  var tweetList = [];

  function parseTweets(){
    if (tweetList == 0){
      $("#tweet-container").text("No tweets currently found.")
    }  else {
        //tweets are existing, so parse and display them
        $.each(parseTweets, function(key, value){
          //console.log(key)
          // console.log(value.user)
          // console.log(value.content)
          var tweetKey = value.key;
          var tweetUser = value.user;
          var tweetContent = value.content;
          $("#tweet-container").append(
            "<div class=\"media\"><div class=\"media-body\">" + tweetContent + "</br> via " + tweetUser.username + " | " + <a href="#">View</a> + "</div></div><hr/>"
          )
        })
      }
    }

  $.ajax({
    url:"/api/tweet/",
    data:{
      "q": query
    },
    method: "GET",
    success:function(data){
      //console.log(data)
      tweetList = data
      parseTweets()

    },
    error:
    function(data){
      console.log("error")
      console.log(data)
    }


  })



});
</script>
```

**strong text**

Comment: You can't make a cross-origin XHR request from a local html file without configuring the browser on your local machine to explicitly allow CORS violations. This is done for security reasons.

The other option is to run a local web server, otherwise you're going to run into CORS issues.

Comment: Hey Josh,thank you for your reply.
I'm running it on a local surver, i'm trying django - so running it on a localhost python server.also tell me more about the-- "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" error message.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the quotes to resolve your syntax error:

```
$("#tweet-container").append("<div class=\"media\"><div class=\"media-body\">" + tweetContent + " </br> via " + tweetUser.username + " | " + "<a href=\"#\">View</a></div></div><hr/>")
```

Comment: Can you provide some kind of error or description of what isn't working?...

Comment: It seems that it still is a syntax error.
It is saying that, Error:{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Comment: Stackoverflow put some weird line breaks in which break the syntax. I've edited my answer to try and fix the formatting.